# Would writing millions of strings through a Writer be a memory and performance concern for the java string pool?

Tags: java, memory-management, out-of-memory, string-interning, string-pool

So say I have this code that streams back string back to a client with millions of rows of data. Would all the strings on each write be interned  and thus give a hit on the java memory? If so, why in my case would it be or not be interned?

I can't really tell if I should use a stringbuilder here to append all the things I am gonna write and then write them at the end or just leave it as is

The query would return millions of rows

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream()))) {

            writer.write("[");
            jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[]{name,  age},

                    rs -> {

                        try {

                            writer.write("{\"id1\":" + rs.getInt("id1") + ",");

                            writer.write("\"id2\":" + rs.getInt("id2") + "}");

                        } catch (IOException e) {

                            log.log(Level.ERROR, e);

                        }

                    });

            writer.write("]");

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw e;

        }
```

Comment: If you are concerned about memory usage, you should NOT collect everything in one big StringBuilder. Just send each piece to the `writer` as soon as it is ready.

Comment: ps# You're swallowing an error in your inner `catch` clause.  You're logging the error and then continueing as if nothing wrong happened.

Comment: Your strings will be gc  once they each execute and the writer object will efficiently write a new one. So as you can see, it is subjective as to whether or not you view that as a memory problem during runtime. We'd need more information on your objectives to fully understand what you mean. Like you can see how this is vauge?

Comment: Also, how big are "a million rows" in memory?  Seems like a lot, interesting that the client can't page through the data, so that million rows will need to be kept in memory.  And remember if they are read from the harddrive - (feel free to correct me if I'm wrong or oversimplifying things) harddrives are syncronous mediums, so only one thread will be able to read from the harddrive at a time (versus memory from which multiple threads can read at the same time)

Comment: Excellent point Thilo.      
Ns du Toit, I wasn't sure what else I can do from there in terms of the exception.             
Also pagination wasn't an option, the api is ruthless on the db(requires careful calls from client)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No `String`s will ever be interned at run-time unless you call `.intern()` on them.**  You're not in any danger of blowing up the intern pool.

It might help speed things up if you assembled your strings with  `StringBuilder`, but it won't make any difference in overall memory consumption.  Every string you are making is gone and forgotten once your `BufferedWriter` and `OutputStreamWriter` have finished writing it to its destination.

Comment: Well, if that table really returns a million rows, and you assemble them all in a StringBuilder, that will cause memory pressure. But I assume you meant to say that assembling each line before writing it (instead of two writes of a concatenation each) makes no difference (which is true).

Comment: Hmm, I've always been told that strings get interned in run time and thats why we should use a StringBuilder. For example, if you did a big loop and appended strings on each iteration, it'd take a really long time, whereas stringbuilder is fast. Why is that? Isn't that due to string interning?

Comment: The reason for using `StringBuilder`s has nothing to do with interning of `String`s.  It's because every `s1 + s2` on `String`s amounts to `(new StringBuilder(s1).append(s2).toString()`.  If you use your own `StringBuilder` to carry out several string appends, you save an unneeded `new StringBuilder()` and `.toString()` per append.